# NSIS: Deleting a folder upon uninstall

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to delete the `Startmenu\XXX` folder and `Program Files\XXX` menu upon uninstall for the application.

Tried `RMDir /r` but this does not work for me.
(Windows 7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RMDir is the correct instruction, your path is probably wrong.

A common issue with startmenu removal is forgetting to use RequestExecutionLevel, see [this page on the NSIS wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista)

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can help you detect path and privilege issues...

Answer (score 5):

Occasionally Windows won't let you remove a folder when it's still in use. The solution is to mark the folder (and/or files) for deletion on next system reboot. For this, use the flag /REBOOTOK

For files:

```
Delete /REBOOTOK "<filename>"
```

For folders

```
RMDir /R /REBOOTOK directoryname
```

After next reboot, the files/folders will be removed.

See also: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/RMDir

Answer (score 3):

Here's your solution:
add "SetShellVarContext all"

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista

Example code:

```
OutFile Win7.exe
Name Win7

Section
  SetShellVarContext all
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\Win7 Testing"
  CreateShortcut  "$SMPROGRAMS\Win7 Testing\win7test.lnk" "$WINDIR\notepad.exe"
  WriteUninstaller "$EXEDIR\uninst.exe"
SectionEnd

Section uninstall
  SetShellVarContext all
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Win7 Testing\win7test.lnk"
  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\Win7 Testing"
SectionEnd
```

-joedf